# Efficiency of for loops in python3

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python (3), having mostly experience with R as main programming language. While in R `for`-loops have mostly the same functionality as in Python, I was taught to avoid using it for big operations and instead use `apply`, which is more efficient.

My question is: how efficient are `for`-loops in Python, are there alternatives and is it worth exploring those possibilities as a Python newbie?

For example:

```
p = some_candidate_parameter_generator(data)
for i in p:
    fit_model_with paramter(data, i)
```

Bear with me, it is tricky to give an example without going too much into specific code. But this is something that in `R` I would have writting with `apply`, especially if `p` is large.

Comment: can you use an example of a big operation?

Comment: in sigle sentance ,they are as efficient as your logic

Comment: according to the doc, apply function is "Deprecated since version 2.3": https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=apply#apply. and it does just not exist in Python 3

Comment: This is hard to answer in general and really depends on what you need to achieve. If you need to loop over something, then this is probably as efficient as it can be. However, if you can, for example, use `map` **which produces another generator**, that is a completely different thing and potentially much more efficient. But it's also an apples to oranges comparison.

Comment: @Tryph and there is no equivalent?

Comment: @Tryph Python's `apply` has probably nothing to do with R's `apply`.

Comment: @deceze Hmm, from what I can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) it seems that it is pretty similar to `apply` in `R` in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments correctly point out that for loops are "only as efficient as your logic"; however, the `range` and `xrange` in Python do have performance implications, and this may be what you had in mind when asking this question. *These methods have nothing to do with the intrinsic performance of for loops though.*

In Python 3.0, `xrange` is now implicitly just `range`; however, in Python versions less than 3.0, there used to be a distinction – `range` loaded your entire iterable into memory, and then iterated over each item, while `xrange` was more akin to a generator, where each item was loaded into memory only when needed and then removed from memory after it was iterated over.

**After your updated question:**

In other words, if you have a giant list of items that you need to iterate over via a for loop, it is often more memory efficient to use a generator, not a list or a tuple, etc. Again though, this has nothing to do with how the Python for-loop operates, but more to do with what you're iterating over. If in doubt, use a generator, and your memory-efficiency will be as good as it will get with Python.

Comment: Hmm, I am unfamiliar to generators, so I'll definitely have to read more about that.